# Duplicating rows in one select MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-records

At first I would like greet all Users and apologize for my english :). 
I'm new user on this forum.
I have a question about MySQL queries.
I have table Items with let say 2 columns for example itemsID and ItemsQty.

```
itemsID ItemsQty
11  2
12  3
13  3
15  5
16  1
```

I need select itemsID but duplicated as many times as indicated in column ItemsQty.

```
itemsID ItemsQty
11  2
11  2
12  3
12  3
12  3
13  3
13  3
13  3
15  5
15  5
15  5
15  5
15  5
16  1
```

I tried that query:

```
SELECT items.itemsID, items.itemsQty

FROM base.items 

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(

  SELECT items.itemsQty AS Qty FROM base.items

) AS Numbers ON items.itemsQty <=Numbers.Qty

ORDER BY items.itemsID;
```

but it doesn't work correctly.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: have you try distinct?

Comment: Thanks for answers.
I can't use the "distinct"  because i need the duplicate of the records but as many times as indicate column itemsQty. 
I need print special labels so i need let say 2 labels from first record, 3 labels from second record etc.

Comment: just do it with script - I have answered below - if you specify a language and I know it I can adjust my answer (although my pseudo-code should probably help you if you have programmed before)

Comment: Ok Sussed how to do it with MySQL but you need another table for it to work correctly. See updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL answer - Option 1**

You need another table called `numbers` with the numbers 1 up to the maximum for ItemsQuantity

```
Table: NUMBERS

1
2
3
4
5
......
max number for ItemsQuantity
```

Then the following SELECT statement will work

```
SELECT ItemsID, ItemsQty
FROM originaltable
JOIN numbers
    ON originaltable.ItemsQty >= numbers.number
ORDER BY ItemsID, number
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f1255/1) -> you should always set-up a fiddle like this when you can - it makes everyone's life easier!!!

**code answer - option 2**

MySQL probably won't do what you want 'cleanly' without a second table (although some clever person might know how)

What is wrong with doing it with script?

Just run a `SELECT itemsID, ItemsQty FROM table`

Then when looping through the result just do (pseudo code as no language specified)

```
newArray = array();  // new array

While Rows Returned from database{ //loop all rows returned

    loop number of times in column 'ItemsQty'{

          newArray -> add 'ItemsID'


    }


}//end of while loop
```

This will give you a new array

```
0 => 11

1 => 11

2 => 12

3 => 12

4 => 12

5 => 13
```

etc.

Comment: Thank You very much! The first option is great solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select DISTINCT items.itemsID, items.itemsQty From base.items left outer join (select items.itemsQty as Qty from base.items) As Numbers On items.itemsQty <=Numbers.Qty  
order by items.itemsID;
```

Use **DISTINCT** to remove duplicates. Read more here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Thanks for answers. I can't use the "distinct" because I need the duplicate of the records but as many times as indicate column itemsQty. I need print special labels so i need let say 2 labels from first record, 3 labels from second record etc.

Comment: Ah, yes. Let me think

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I understood what you asked differently than everyone else so I hope I answer you question. What I would basically do is -

1. create a new table for those changes.
2. Create a mysql procedure which given a line in the original table add new lines to the new table - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/loop.html
3. Run this procedure for each line in the original table.

Comment: Thanks for answers.
I need print special labels so i need let say 2 labels from first record, 3 labels from second record etc. I'm trying use the crystal reports for that. The print will be used often for selected records so I need the simplest solution.

Answer (score -1):

try this to get distinct values from both columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT itemsID FROM items
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT itemsQty FROM items
```